# Best way to merge binary files in Java

Tags: java, disk

I'm developing a basic download manager that can download a file over http using multiple connections. At the end of the download, I have several temp file containing each a part of the file.

I now want to merge them into a single file.

It's not hard to do so, simply create an output stream and input streams and pipe the inputs into the output in the good order.

But I was wondering: is there a way to do it more efficiently? I mean, from my understanding what will happen here is that the JVM will read byte per byte the inputs, and write byte per byte the output.

So basically I have :
- read byte from disk
- store byte in memory
- some CPU instructions will probably run and the byte will probably be copied into the CPU's cache
- write byte to the disk

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the process on the disk? I don't know if I'm understandable, but basically to tell the disk "hey disk, take these files of yours and make one with them"

In a short sentence, I want to reduce the CPU & memory usage to the lowest possible.

Comment: here you go: https://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/

Comment: Concatenating files is too rare an operation to get added to common low level DOS operations. But the link above goes a long way. Note that one of its optimizations is to use a large intermediate buffer with a size of a multiple of (the most common) disk page size.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: That's look a pretty good way to do it, thanks

Comment: @RadLexus: I thought so :(

Comment: @Tiller you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory it may be possible to do this operation on a file system level: you could append the block list from one inode to another without moving the data. This is not very practical though, most likely you would have to bypass your operating system and access the disk directly.

The next best thing may be using [`FileChannel.transferTo` or `transferFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-) methods:

> This method is potentially much more efficient than a simple loop that reads from this channel and writes to the target channel. Many operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the filesystem cache to the target channel without actually copying them.

You should also test reading and writing large blocks of bytes using streams or `RandomAccessFile` - it may still be faster than using channels. Here's a good article about [testing sequential IO performance in Java](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.de/2011/12/java-sequential-io-performance.html).

Comment: I ran some test of my own, and for large files it would appear that channels are the fatest in my case. It's 5 to 10 times faster in my test case. Thank you.